# Table of contents of custom environment

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, lists

I am new to the world of latex and currently I am facing the following situation.

I have a series of `pdf` documents I want to include in a `chapter` of a book.

In the beginning of the chapter I would like to have a table of contents of `my_pdf`s, showing:

`the title ...... page`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
   \listmyPDF

    \begin{my_pdf}{Title to show in ToC}
        \lipsum[1] % later will use \includepdf
    \end{my_pdf}

    \begin{my_pdf}{Title2 to show in ToC}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{my_pdf}

    \begin{my_pdf}{Title3 to show in ToC}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{my_pdf}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! You don't need an environment if you just want to add it to the toc. You can just use the options provided for `\includepdf`. See the `pdfpages` documentation.

Comment: Actually, scratch that suggestion. I just tried it and either it is horribly buggy or I just don't understand how it is meant to work.

Answer (score 0):

`pdfpages` has an `addtotoc` option. Unfortunately, it either doesn't do what I thought or it is very buggy. The former is overwhelmingly more likely, but I couldn't work it out. I also discovered that, although I add included PDFs to the toc on a regular basis, I'm not using the option either.

So the simplest solution might be a simple wrapper which adds the toc line and includes the PDF.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \chichaincpdf { O {pages={-}} mm }
{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \includepdf[#1]{#3}%
}
```

This defines a new command, `\chichaincpdf` which takes one optional argument and two required ones. The optional argument is a list of options to be given to `\includepdf`. I've set `pages={-}` as default, but you could leave it empty if you only want to include the first page most of the time. Or you could add to it if you want something more elaborate.

The second argument is the title to be printed in the toc. The third is the file name to be included.

So

```
\chichaincpdf{A4 Sample}{example-image-a4}
```

will print 'A4 Sample' in the toc and include `example-image-a4.pdf`.

I've added PDFs at the `section` level in the toc. If you want them added as something else (`subsection` or `chapter`, say), just modify the `\addcontentsline` accordingly.

[image: TOC entries for chapter including two PDFs]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\NewDocumentCommand \chichaincpdf { O {pages={-}} mm }
{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \includepdf[#1]{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My PDFs}

\kant[1-4]

\chichaincpdf{A4 Sample}{example-image-a4}

\chichaincpdf{Numbered A4 Sample}{example-image-a4-numbered}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Would this be able to work with `\includegraphics` if required?